# Associated controller in "each" block in template

Tags: ember.js

Let's say we have the following templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nodes">
    ...
    {{controller-property-1}}
    {{outlet}}
    ...
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nodes/index">
    ...
    {{controller-property-2}}
    {{#each model}}
        {{controller-property-3}}
    {{/each}}
    ...
</script>
```

To define `controller-property-1` I just need to place it in `App.NodesController`. `controller-property-2` must be defined in `App.NodesIndexController`.

What is the related controller for `{{controller-property-3}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `{{#each}}` the scope of 'this' refers to the model. You can lookup the controller's property as `{{controller.controller-property-3}}`

[Sample fiddle](http://jsbin.com/esevox/2/edit)